# BASH split single line into key, value pair. Ex A,B,C | 1,2,3 to A,1 B,2 C,3

Tags: bash, split, zsh, pcap, tshark

I'm using Tshark to split some data up. The problem is the data displays on a single line. In order to use it, I'd like to split it up into key-value pairs. For example:

Tshark data-
`a,b,c,d,e,f,g | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

Would like to format like this -  `a,1 b,2 c,3 d,4 e,5 f,6 g,7`

or - `[{a,1},{b,2}] etc..`

Thanks!

Comment: `bash` or `zsh`?

Comment: Do it in multiple steps. First split the whole line on `|` into two variables. Then split each of those variables into arrays on `,`. Then loop through the array indexes, combining the corresponding elements of each array.

Comment: If this is a bash question, why do you have zsh in the tags? They're two different shells, and **not** mutually compatible.

Comment: might help to know how you plan to use this data and thus an appropriate way of saving/storing the reformatted data (eg, (associative) array? space-delimited pairs in a single string? yaml/json/xml structure?)

Comment: In my case it's probably easier to process string in python and run another bash script N times from there than try to do it all in bash. Something like this https://pastebin.com/YcpSwHPq

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^ - note bash; not zsh, not sh

processLine() {
  local data idx      # declare locals so we don't pollute global namespace
  local -a arr1 arr2  # declare local arrays separately
  data=$1             # assign our first positional argument to $data

  # no separator? bail out early
  [[ $data = *" | "* ]] || {
    echo "ERROR: Data not in expected form" >&2
    return 1
  }

  # break our two variables into two separate arrays
  IFS=, read -r -a arr1 <<<"${data%%' | '*}"
  IFS=, read -r -a arr2 <<<"${data#*' | '}"

  # iterate over those arrays by index/key to pair items up
  for idx in "${!arr1[@]}"; do
    printf '%s,%s ' "${arr1[$idx]}" "${arr2[$idx]}"
  done
  printf '\n'  # add a trailing newline
}

processLine 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7'
```

See this running at https://ideone.com/6Ugk0H

Answer (score 0):

Try this awk

```
$ echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7" | awk -F"[|, ]+" ' { for(i=1;i<=NF/2;i++) printf $i "," $(i+NF/2) " " } '
a,1 b,2 c,3 d,4 e,5 f,6 g,7
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this `zsh` also, a `zsh` solution using just its parameter expansion:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

data="a,b,c,d,e,f,g | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7"

# Split on pipe into an array
halves=( ${(s:|:)data} ) 
# Split the first array element on comma, first removing trailing spaces
first=( ${(s:,:)${halves[1]%% }} )
# Same with the second element and leading spaces
second=( ${(s:,:)${halves[2]## }} )

# Merge the two arrays by alternating elements, and print out two elements
# at a time so it looks like
# a,1 b,2 c,3 d,4 e,5 f,6 g,7
printf "%s,%s " ${first:^second}
printf "\n"

# Or to render as
# [{a,1},{b,2},{c,3},{d,4},{e,5},{f,6},{g,7}]
pairs=$(printf "{%s,%s}\001" ${first:^second})
printf "[%s]\n" "${(j:,:)${(ps:\001:)pairs}}"
```